# Binomial Test in SAS and R - Different Results

Tags: r, sas, binomial-theorem

I need to replicate a binomial test from R to SAS but I'm obtaining different results (or maybe I am misinterpreting the SAS results).

In order to explain my problem in an easy way, I will use data from this wikipedia [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test) because it provides the final solution;

Suppose you want to calculate the probability of obtaining 51 or more 6s in a sample of 235 roll of a fair die with 6 faces, so that the true probability of rolling a 6 on each trial is 1/6.
The final solution should be **0.02654**.

In R, the code to do is the following:

```
binom.test(51,235,(1/6),alternative = "greater")
```

and the obtained results are:

> Exact binomial test
>
> data:  51 and 235 number of successes = 51, number of trials = 235,
>   **p-value = 0.02654**
>   alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is greater than 0.1666667
>   95 percent confidence interval:
>   0.1735253 1.0000000
>   sample estimates: probability of success
>                0.2170213

When in SAS the equivalent should be given by:

```
DATA DICEROLL;
ROLL=51;
FREQQ=235;
PROB=1/6;
RUN;

data _null_;
set diceroll;
call symput("probability",prob);
run;

PROC FREQ DATA=DiceRoll ;
    TABLES FREQQ / BINOMIAL (P=&probability.) ALPHA=0.05;
    EXACT  BINOMIAL ;
    WEIGHT ROLL ;
RUN;
```

But [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrq2s.png) is the results I obtain (in which there is no p-value = 0.02654)

I tried in several ways to reconcile my results(tried all the three alternatives in R, tried to invert ROLL and FREQQ in sas because I wasn't sure) but I still haven't found a solution.
Do binom.test and proc freq + BINOMIAL perform at least the same test? 
Am I misinterpreting the SAS output?

Thank you in advance for you precious help!

============================== UPDATE ============================

I tried both proposed methodology by reeza and BEMR and I feel I am close to the solution!
**@BEMR:** as I wrote and explained bettere in the comment,  how should I adapt %r(1,6) if my variable is dichotomic? Your code works with the example of a 6-faced die but in my real case, my success variable assume values between 0 and 1, so I am not sure of what I have to do (I apologize if I did not mention it at the beginning)

**@REEZA**: Your solution seems to work but I had to remove the /2; I guess your first solution calculates p-values as a two sided test not one sided. 
Anyway, the results are fine but there are huge differences between SAS and R when the number of success is 0 or close to 0 (1,2,3). Do you know any workaround for this? Or better, is it safe to assume that the test is unreliable in both cases?
The following pictures are my results with the reeza method, thank you all for your precious cooperation!
[image] 
[image]

Comment: It looks like it think you have observed 100%, not 21.7% - how do you specify the number of successes?

Comment: Does it really require 14 lines in SAS to replicate the functionality of that single line in R? In any event, `n = 235` is a reasonably large sample size. You can do a quick normal approximation and independently verify that the R result makes sense but that any computation which suggests that the p-value is < 0.0001 must be flawed/

Comment: No, it doesn't. In R you've done a theoretical calcualtion, whereas in SAS you've done a simulation type calculation. Rather use the PPROB or QPROB as appropriate within a data step to get the probability.

Comment: Sorry, you want the CDF or PDF but my brain is a bit fried at the moment. I'll post what I think is close but you should verify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously don't need to have the variables set up this way, but this more of a one to one type comparison. SAS doesn't have the capacity to do a one sided test that I saw within the function but I didn't read up much on it or try and figure if it's right. But this the type of approach you should be using in SAS to get similar numbers, not PROC FREQ.

```
    data demo;
nSuccesses=51;
prob_success=1/6;
nTrials = 235;

y=(1-cdf('BINOM', nsuccesses, prob_success, ntrials))/2;
run;

proc print data=demo;
run;
```

http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p1cxa81efqtsszn12ueyitll9esw.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=ja#p03dt2kdzjjucxn198ytlpnrf1r4

Comment: Post the code you have via editing your question and I'll take another look into it.

Comment: Sorry, today I'm a bit fried too! My comment referred to another methodology I tried with which I obtain confidence intervals but no p-values (1-betainv(.025,(&trials.-&nsuccess.),&nsuccess.+1). Your methodology seems to work but with some little issue. I will update my question asap

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to compare binom.test and proc freq + BINOMIAL you could using a simulation in SAS. The following code provides an example:

When the dice is rolled 235 and the result can be 1,...,6.

```
*Create df: random roll;
*macro: random int between min and max;;
  %macro r(min,max);
(&min + floor((1+&max-&min)*rand("uniform"))) 
   %mend;
  data df;
  f = 0;
  do i = 1 to 235; *number of trials;
    x = %r(1,6); *call macro %r() to generate random number between 1,...,6; 
if x = 6 then f = f + 1; *if the random number = 6, add freq from the previous;
relative = f/i; *relative freq;
 output;
end;
run;

*plot relative freq, reference line (1/6), probability of rolling 6;
symbol v=dot c=red;
proc gplot data=df;
plot relative * i/overlay vref=0.16666667 href=500 lh=3;
run;
quit;
```

[image]

This follows an example from here: http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~lfindsen/stat503/Lab2.pdf

```
*exact binomial using proc freq and simulated data; 
*test if simulation is different from the hypothized 1/6;
proc freq data = df;
tables x / binomial (level=6 p=.166667); 
exact binomial;
run;
```

When 51 cases are 6 out of the 235.

```
*Create df2: assign approx 51 cases of 235 a roll of 6;
 data df2;
 do i = 1 to 235; *number of trials;
x = %r(1,5); 
 output;
 end;
 run;
 data df2;
  set df2;
    if i <= 51 then x = 6; *assign six to rows 1 to 51; 
  run;

  *exact binomial using proc freq and simulated data; 
  *test if simulation is different from the hypothized 1/6;
  proc freq data = df2;
tables x / binomial (level=6 p=.166667); 
exact binomial;
  run;
```

exact binomial one-sided p-value = 0.0265
[image]

**============================== UPDATE ============================**

For the binary variable [0=2184,1=72] instead of using the macro, you could do the following:

```
    data df3;
    input success n;
    datalines;
    0 2184
    1 72
    ;

    proc freq data=df3;
    weight n; *number of obs for [0,1];
    tables success / binomial (level=2 p=0.509); 
    run;
```

Comment: What I need to do irl, is to check if the estimated probability underestimates the observed rate of success.
Suppose you have:
Success=72; Trials=2256; SuccRate=3.19%; Prob Estimated=5.09%.
The experiment can assume only values of 0 (fail) or 1 (success).

The null hypothesis in R is that the true probability of success is less than 0.509 and thus for p-values > alpha the test is passed.
The R code would be:
> binom.test(72,2256,0.509,alternative = "greater").
Result I need -> p-value = 1.

How should I adapt %r(1,6) if my variable is dichotomic?

Comment: If I get the logic of the code right, it should be %r(0,0) and then if i<=72 then x=1. However, when I run the proc freq I still can't obtain the R results. What can I do in your opinion? Isn't redundant to create df in this way if my variable is dichotomic?

Comment: @BEMR Why is the two sided p-value 0.0531 for SAS when testing two sided? Using R, you get a p-value of 0.04375?